# How Do I Aggregate Recorded Daily Incidents Into Monthly Counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, count

I have a large pandas dataframe of daily crime incidents. One of my columns ('date') is datatype datetime64[ns].

Take, for example, the dataframe below:

| ID | Date | Crime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 987AL4 | 1991-08-15 | Robbery |
| 987AL4 | 1991-08-16 | Asasult |
| 124576IL | 1991-09-21 | Breaking and Entering |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 4689CA | 2016-08-17 | Sexaul Assault |

What I would like to do is create a new dataframe with monthly counts of incidents for each year and each ID.
So, ideally, the resulting dataframe might look something like:

| ID | Month | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 987AL4 | 1991-08 | 200,870 |
| 124576IL | 1991-08 | 190,000 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 45678CA | 2016-08 | 60,000 |

I've tried various groupby and count methods, but I've had no luck. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: `df['Month'] = df.Date.apply(lambda d: d.strftime("%Y-%m"))` will create the month column. Then `df.groupby(by=('Month', 'ID')).agg('sum')`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget. You can avoid to use `apply` using `dt` accessor then use `value_counts` instead of `groupby_count`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your `DatetimeIndex` as `PeriodIndex` and use `value_counts`:

```
out = (df.value_counts(['ID', df['Date'].dt.to_period('M').rename('Month')])
         .rename('Count').reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
         ID    Month  Count
0    987AL4  1991-08      2
1  124576IL  1991-09      1
2    4689CA  2016-08      1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['987AL4', '987AL4', '124576IL', '4689CA'],
                   'Date': ['1991-08-15', '1991-08-16', '1991-09-21', '2016-08-17'],
                   'Crime': ['Robbery', 'Asasult', 'Breaking and Entering', 'Sexual Assault']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')
print(df)
"""
         ID       Date                  Crime    Month
0    987AL4 1991-08-15                Robbery  1991-08
1    987AL4 1991-08-16                Asasult  1991-08
2  124576IL 1991-09-21  Breaking and Entering  1991-09
3    4689CA 2016-08-17         Sexual Assault  2016-08
"""
df_new = df.groupby(['ID', 'Month']).size().reset_index(name='Case_Count_wrt_ID_Month')

print(df_new)

"""
         ID    Month  Count
0  124576IL  1991-09      1
1    4689CA  2016-08      1
2    987AL4  1991-08      2

"""
```